# how to Type casting of DocumentReference to Arraylist in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

After fetching data from firestore.When i type cast the documentReferance arraylist in kotlin than its work some time and some time not cast the values.I am using this code.Thanks in advance

```
 var mParentss = data.document.get("parents") as ArrayList<DocumentReference>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `data.document.get("parents").toObject(YourPOJO)` and then convert to your pojo object

Comment: What happens when it isn't working? Do you have an error? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Anshul i am using foreach on documents.documentChanges and inside this i have parents key with array of documentreferance

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't have any error but its not parsing the data correctly

Comment: What do you mean by "its not parsing the data correctly"? What exactly happens?

Comment: @Code see [this](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/8aa5f22c41492b5823066c19550c40287dfbfa80/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/util/database/SyncUtil.kt#L134) , here I manipulate the document onSuccess to POJO by [`toObject`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) using [My POJO](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/8aa5f22c41492b5823066c19550c40287dfbfa80/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/data/model/FirestoreQueryObject.kt)

Comment: @AlexMamo its means some time its parse corectly sometime skip to parse